# Taking the square root of my DV solved problems with scewness in residuals. What does this mean?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, normality-assumption, qq-plot

As you could probably guess, I am -very- new to both statistics and R. SO the obvious answer would be that I have to get home and study more, but I would also appreciate some pointers here. 
I have done a multilevel regression like this:

modelr6 <-lmer(LRcongruence ~ wrclmch1 + gndr +
                 (1+ wrclmch1|cntryN), data=dfComplete,
               REML = FALSE)

, but got back a very scewed QQplot of residuals. :[image]

Now, after doing this instead: 
modelr7 <-lmer(sqrt(LRcongruence) ~ wrclmch1 + gndr +
                 (1+ wrclmch1|cntryN), data=dfComplete,
               REML = FALSE) 
, it looks much better. Not saying its good, but way better.: [image]

Is there an obvious explanation to why the model works better predicting the square root of DV then the DV itself?

I also tried doing log transforming the DV + 1, which also kinda worked, just not as well: 
modelrc7 <-lmer(log(1 + LRcongruence) ~ wrclmch2 + gndr +
                 (1+ wrclmch2|cntryN), data=dfComplete,
               REML = FALSE)
. 
[image]

Is either taking the sqare root or log transforming preferred over the other in statistics in general?

Appriciate your help.

Comment: Would you please post the raw data, or a link to the raw data?